# Xcode does not recognize OpenGL function glPrimitiveRestart()

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, sdl

from what i understand, glPrimitiveRestart() has been a function of openGL since version 3, but somehow when I try to use it Xcode says "use of undeclared identifier." Seems like I'm on OpenGL 4 at least so I'm not sure what i could be missing. It has no problem with this function glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART) or any of the many other OpenGL functions I've used in my application.

heres what my includes look like:

```
#include <SDL2/SDL_opengl.h>
#include <OpenGL/glu.h>
```

and heres what I'm trying to do in my init function:

```
glEnable(GL_PRIMITIVE_RESTART);
glPrimitiveRestart(123456789);
```

Any idea why it wouldn't recognize a random function like that?

Im on Xcode 7, SDL 2, and seem to be in OpenGL 4.1 as far as i can tell.

Comment: just an update, I've tried adding `#include <OpenGL/gl.h>`
`#include <OpenGL/gl3.h>` and
`#include <OpenGL/gl3ext.h>` and still same result

Comment: THANKS! i don't know why that other question failed to show up in my many google searches